# Graphic grouping in QGIS Map Layout

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, legend, grouping

In QGIS 3.18, I'm trying to draw symbols/graphic for Map Legend manually in the Map Layout. When grouping them, it shows the big box like the screenshot below and seems not convenient to continue working on it. It should show the box fitting to the group of the symbols!

How can we solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the reason you want to create legend manually ? You may find solution to create a legend item that suits your needs or create a html table to align "manual legend" and integrate image you want.

Comment: Are you sure there is no empty layout item in the group that is causing its extent to be so large? Also check that the frames of each grouped item fit tightly to their content